# "Undefined reference to function" even with include

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker

I'm having some trouble building a project. I'll try to reproduce the error here.

I have a    `file.c`    where I want to use `function()` that is declared in `header.h` and defined in `header.c` (that isn't in the same directory as `header.h`).

So far very simple, I added `#include "header.h"` in `file.c` and the option `-I/path/to/header` to the compiler, since `header.h` isn't in any other include path.

I thought this should be enough for the linker to find the definition of `function()`, but I still get the error

```
Undefined reference to 'function'
```

Now it gets a bit more complicated, the project is quite big, and `file.c` and `header.h` are in very different paths, I don't know if that makes any difference since I include the full path for the compiler.

Also, the building process first generates a `file.o`, that is parcially linked with others `.o`, which is after linked with with more `.o`, that generates an executable, and is at the point of genereting the executable that the error occurs.

I did `nm` to the partial `.o` to try to get more information, and the `function()` appears as undefined, which I guess is expected, but I don't know why the linker isn't able to find the definition of `function()`. I have no idea what I'm missing here...

Help please?

**EDIT:**

I know `header.c` is compiled before `file.c`, but if I simply try to add `header.o` to the command line, I get another error:

```
No rule to make target 'header.o', needed by 'file.o'
```

I imagine this is because the directories are different, is there any way to give the path to `header.o` to the linker?

Comment: it's not an include problem (as it successfully compile file.c), the linker try to find the implementation of the function, header.o must not be given to the linker

Comment: You still need to compile and link `header.c`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do it? I edited the question with more information